# how to migrate a multi-value term reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I am setting up a drupal migration where the destination node contains a multi-value taxonomy term_reference field, called `'field_features'`. The machine name of the drupal taxonomy vocabulary of the field is called `'voc_features'`.

My field mapping for this field is configured like this:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_features:create_term')->defaultValue(true);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_features:ignore_case')->defaultValue(true);

//i don't have tid's in the source, so i leave the source_type for what it is
$this->addUnmigratedDestinations(array('field_features:source_type'));

//i link the drupal vocabulary to the multivalue field.
$this->addFieldMapping('voc_features', 'field_features')->separator('|');
```

The terms are added in the `'voc_features'` vocabulary, but not in the `'field_features'` field.

When i add the field mapping like i do with all the other fields:

```
//my source fields have the same name as my destination fields
$this->addFieldMapping('field_features', 'field_features')->separator('|');
```

i get the following error:

*strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given File ...\sites\all\modules\migrate\plugins\destinations\fields.inc, line 402*

Other single value term_reference fields import just fine.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The migration of term doesn't allow to migrate multi-value. You have to process the source ahead.

1. Create a new migration and import the data to terms of vocabulary named `'voc_features'` at first.
2. Add a dependence to your current migration using previous migration. Such as `$this->dependencies = array('MigrateXXXMigration');`.
3. The field mapping should be like this,`$this->addFieldMapping('field_features', 'Features')->arguments(array('source_type' => 'tid'));`
4. In the `function prepareRow($row)`, you should prepare the `Features` field and put it into your `$row` variable. `$row->Features=array(tid1,tid2,tid3);`. The 'tid1','tid2' and 'tid3' should be replace the live tid from your term tables.

Comment: Have you managed to do this with the :ignore_case argument set to true?

Comment: Is there an issue open about this? Having to do this amount of parsing makes migrate framework a lot less useful.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for migrate module it seems to be a bug in the module.This issue happens when ignorecase is set to true while migrating multivalue fields. You may want to open a new issue in ALB migrate module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a migration also at the moment.  I agree with Tony that you could write something using prepareRow() that would achieve what you want .   Could you post your full extension class of RcnMigrateMigration, I'll see if I can make any sense of it.

Comment: I managed to get the migrate up and running with a separate migration for the terms first. However i did not use tid as source_type. This wasn't needed. I also didn't use the prepareRow() for this. I just used the 'separator' argument in addFieldMapping().